# Using remote server in Visual Studio Code terminal?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, putty

I recently switched to using Visual Studio Code from Sublime Text and have a question about the terminal functionality.  It looks like "Integrated Terminal" that appears at the bottom is mounted to the local file system out of the box.

What I'm wondering is if I can replace this local terminal with a remote server?  I have the hostname, port, and login credentials and would love to be able to navigation the file system on our remote server (like using MobaXterm, PuTTy, etc) and then open code files in Visual Studio Code instead of vim or emacs.  Is this possible?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 9):

UPDATE:  I have figured out how to rig this into VS code.

You can download git bash online and it will be mounted to your local machine. In VS Code, you can then Ctrl+Shift+P and type "Open User Settings". In the right pane, add this setting:

[image]

This will replace the default integrated terminal in VSCode with the git bash CLI client that was just installed in the location in the screenshot above.  Now that you have your local file system mounted in VScode, you can execute:

`ssh username@hostname -p <port>`

Comment: the command is `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"`